# Use of 'that' and 'for' in "What do you think we can do to help her?"

Tags: prepositions, relative-pronouns, ellipsis, syntax

This question came up in our school test and required the students to translate the sentence from Korean.

The sentence they were looking for was...

> What do you think we can do to help her?

However, some students wrote:

> What do you think **that** we can do to help her

and

> What do you think we can do **for** her to help?

They sound correct but what is the rule(if any) the English teacher at the school is curious and I'm at a loss for a specific rule to quote her offhand.

Comment: I wrote about this kind of [omission of *that*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/56590/3281) once. [Another answer of mine](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/67966/3281) might be a good start for the use of *for* in your example sentence, though my feeling is that a good explanation of this *for* may be found in typical dictionaries. This link is also useful: ["that" omission, subject-verb distance - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143095/that-omission-subject-verb-distance).

Answer (score 1):

> What do you think we can do to help her?

-- This sounds ok to me, however if I was going to write this, I might break it into two questions `What do you think? What can we do to help her?`

---

> What do you think **that** we can do to help her

-- `that` seems superfluous, but not inherently wrong

---

> What do you think we can do **for** her to help?

For is generally used to indicate the use of something, or because of something, or for some duration.

To is generally used to indicate a direction of movement, a destination, a relationship between two concepts, or a period of time.

I don't think these work well together in this sentence. Adding `for` makes it ambiguous. Do you want `to help her`, or do you want `her to help` another. By adding `for` in this way, I then have to wonder, `who` you want to help.